# Distribution of torsion subgroups of elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

By Mazur's theorem, we know the list of possible torsion subgroups of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now, if we order them by height, can we compute the distribution of each possible groups? According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_conjecture), it is known that each group occurs infinitely many times, so maybe all of the possible groups have positive density.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curves with no nontrivial torsion are density 1 in the set of all elliptic curves over $\mathbf{Q}$. This is a result of Duke from 1997 (paper is titled *Courbes elliptiques sur Q sans nombres premiers exceptionnels*).

More specifically, by work of Harron and Snowden, we actually know the leading term in the asymptotic growth of the number of elliptic curves with a given torsion subgroup ordered by height. See Theorems 1.1 and 1.5 in their [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4920.pdf).

Comment: This is exactly I wanted!